# Convert thumbnails into blob for MS Access

Tags: c#, bitmap, blob, thumbnails

I have converted .jpg images into a bitmap thumbnail. What I am trying to do now is convert that thumbnail into a blob for MS Access. I have recently started learning computer programming so my code may be sloppy, but, my code right now is:

```
foreach (String files in Directory.GetFiles(dig.SelectedPath))
{
 if (files.EndsWith(".JPG"))
 {
    //convert .jpg to thumbnail
    Image image = new Bitmap(files);
    Image pThumbnail = image.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100, null, new IntPtr());

    //need code entered here to convert pThumbnail into a byte to be able to convert
    //the thumbnail into blob

    //To insert thumbnail into access if I can convert into blob
    string cmdstr = "INSERT into IMGSTR(Path, Images) values(?, ?)";
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, vcon);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", files);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", pThumbnail);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    image.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# Visual Express" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", pThumbnail);
```

With this:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    pThumbnail.Save(ms, pThumbnail.RawFormat);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ms.ToArray())
}
```

Comment: When I replace it with your code I get a "Value cannot be null." Error. I will keep working with your code and see what I can do. Thank you for your response

Comment: You should name your parameters, and you can also try com.Parameters.Add("?").Value = ms.ToArray();